# OpenAPI custom generator with Maven plugin fails with ClassNotFoundException

Tags: maven, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm trying to write an OpenAPI custom generator as mentioned at [openapi-generator
on GitHub](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/v4.1.2/docs/customization.md). Generated the codegen with below command.

```bsh
java -jar modules/openapi-generator-cli/target/openapi-generator-cli.jar meta \
  -o out/generators/my-codegen -n my-codegen -p com.my.company.codegen
```

In the project, I extended the `MyCodegenGenerator` from `JavaJAXRSCXFCDIServerCodegen` and added the required mustache templates. 
When I tried to build the new codegen project, tests failed. So I skipped the tests and built the project. Then I proceeded with the next steps in the guide to use the custom codegen with the Maven plugin. As mentioned in the guide I used `my-codegen` as the `generatorName`:

```xml
<generatorName>my-codegen</generatorName>
```

I'm getting below error:

```java
org.openapitools.codegen.GeneratorNotFoundException:
    Can't load config class with name 'my-codegen'
```

Tried `com.my.company.codegen.MyCodegenGenerator` as well as the `generatorName` and still get a similar error.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find the cause of the issue. I had added the below dependency to the dependencies section of the build initially.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-codegen-openapi-generator</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

After adding the dependency to the dependencies section of the plugin configuration, I was able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to modify the pom.xml. Simply check that in your *Generator class, the overriden method getName() returns the same String as you use in .setGeneratorName(..) method call in your test class.

Also you have to check that the path at .setInputSpec(..) points to a valid yaml file which is out of the box not the case.

Comment: That is the correct answer, wasted hours till figured this out.